# Representation theoretic characterisation of symmetric spaces

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, symmetric-spaces

Let $G$ be a simple compact Lie group and $H$ a closed subgroup. 
Let $\mathfrak{h}\subset \mathfrak{g}$ denote the corresponding Lie algebras. Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be an orthogonal complement to $\mathfrak{h}$ with respect to the killing form. Then we have a representation of $H$ on $\mathfrak{m}$, called the isotropy representation.

Now we have the following nice result (see Theorem 2.12.(c) of this [article](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/papers/symm.ps)):

If $G/H$ is a (Riemannian) symmetric space, then the isotropy representation is irreducible of highest weight $\lambda$ satisfying

(*) $(\lambda, \lambda)=2(\lambda, \alpha)$ for all simple roots $\alpha$ such that $(\lambda,\alpha)\neq 0$.

Conversely, let $V_\lambda$ be an irreducible highest weight representation of $H$ where $\lambda$ satisfies the condition (*). Then there exists a group $G$ containing $H$ such that $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus V_\lambda$ and $G/H$ is a symmetric space, unless $V_\lambda$ is the 7-dimensional representation of $G_2$.

We can summarise the above result as follows: a highest weight representation $V_\lambda$ defines a symmetric space iff $\lambda$ satisfies condition $(*)$ and it is not the 7d representation of $G_2$.

Question: Does condition (*) arise naturally in purely representation theoretic contexts? For instance, does it play a role in the context of representation theory of simple *complex* Lie algebras?

Comment: When $G/K$ is of Hermitian type, the complex isotropy representation is reducible: the holomorphic and antiholomorphic  tangent spaces are separately stable under $K$. I think the statement that you have made is not quite true. The exceptions need to be specified.